# Connected to internet, but web browsers unable to access the web

Tags: macos, network, internet

I am working on a MacBook Pro with OS 10.14.3

This morning, while working, my web browser (Safari) very suddenly stopped being able to access the web (going to google or wikipedia resulted in a gray "no connection" window).  I checked to make sure I was connected to the internet still by doing these things:

- Checked network preferences
- Switched off of ethernet connection to wifi
- Switched wifi channels
- Pinged local and web addresses through terminal
- Sent and received email through Outlook
- Sent and received messages through Slack
- (Switched browsers, just in case it was a Safari-only problem)

Turns out everything I did told me that my computer was connected to the internet.  The only thing that wasn't working was that I wasn't able to access the world wide web through Safari or any other browser I tried.

I got someone from technical support to help (through analog means, since I wasn't able to submit a help ticket without my browser) who fiddled with my VPN and a few other network configurations and was unable to fix the problem.  I restarted the computer and the problem went away (or I wouldn't be able to write to StackExchange).

Anyone knows **what to do to diagnose something like this**, and whether there's a solution to the problem that doesn't require restarting? The fact that our tech support guy had no clue what was happening suggests to me that this was a genuine mystery.